# How to represent the following statement using predicate logic?

Tags: prolog, logic, predicate

The fact that Terry is the leader of CM7 means he is either a Doctor along with expertise in Financial Maths or he is a mathematician along with expertise in statistics and has more than 6 years of experience at x University.

This is what I have until now: leader(terry, cm7)-> (doctor(terry)and expertise (finacial maths, terry)) or (mathematician(tery) and expertise (statistics, terry) and experience(terry, x university)>6))

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Better make sure you get the spellings correct ('tery', 'finacial').